# Taking second input from resistive sesnors

Tags: sensor, resistive

I am designing a device to track the diagnostic of a vehicle. A Vehicle has many sensors working @ 12V or 24V.

As per the scenario, Lets consider a 24V sensor which I need to read. The sensor is a resistive sensor. The analog output from the resistive sensor is going to dashboard of a vehicle via cable. What I need to do is to peel the cable covering, attach a second cable there & take the signal to my PCB which will further be given to an ADC.

How will the original analog signal get affected which is going to dashboard??
Do I need to include some circuitry on PCB to make it possible??

Comment: What car is it that has resistive sensors going directly to the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you will need to use a Buffer circuit to prevent the ADC circuit on your PCB from interfering with the dashboard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier